# rails-translate-routes gem: Is it possible to translate routes but keep (some) original ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, carrierwave, translate

I'm using rails-translate-routes gem to translate "front" routes only.
I'm using carrierwave to upload some files in my admin. Here's an uploader:

```
class CheatsheetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  [...]
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  [...]
end
```

As you see, the path is using the name of the model and the name of the field.

When I try to get the file:

```
link_to "my file", download.cheatsheet.url
```

The path is the default one:

```
http://localhost:3000/uploads/download/cheatsheet/1/a_really_nice_file.pdf
```

And Rails give me a nice Routing error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/uploads/download/cheatsheet/1/a_really_nice_file.pdf"
```

Any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `keep_untranslated_routes: true` in your call to `ActionDispatch::Routing::Translator.translate_from_file`.

For example:

```
ActionDispatch::Routing::Translator.translate_from_file(
  'config/locales/routes.yml',
  no_prefixes: true,
  keep_untranslated_routes: true)
```